# All .local names abruptly stopped resolving

Tags: local

I have a local network run on an ASUS ZenWifi AX mesh system. Up until last week, I was able to connect to other computers via HTTP or SSH by using their name (eg octopi.local). This abruptly stopped. To the best of my knowledge, there was no update to the software nor was I doing any kind of work on the router or network that I could just undo to get this back.

This happens both across clients and across hosts. If I connect directly to the servers with their IP addresses, it works as expected.

1. What exactly is the term for this? Half my issue is that I don't know what to ask Google. ("local DNS" is the closest I could think of)
2. What type of setting should I be looking at to fix this? (or the specific one if you're versed in the ZenWifi AX)
3. (2) notwithstanding, is there another way to work around this?

(redirections to other questions very welcome)

Comment: `.local` addresses are usually handled by *mDNS* on udp port 5353 - not sure why all the bonjour/zeroconf/avahi (3 of the most common implementations of mDNS) would stop working all at once with no changes to anything anywhere

Comment: didn't even know my system did this -- found out it did automatically while trying to do the same. thanks for having this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a DNS server for the local record. Make sure your gear use your router as a DNS server, and the router itselt will use the ISP DNS for unknow query.

Else, if your computer use public DNS, it mean it's local discovery that each computer use to resolve local hostname. If it's the case then you need to make sure the network discovery is allowed inside all your computers.

You will need a real internal DNS server if you want more control.